# Characteristics of African American Vernacular English

Tags: phonetics, english, pronunciation, american-english, aave

The actor in [this Youtube comedy video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7FixvoKBw) seems to be imitating African American Vernacular English (AAVE). I wonder how successful he is.

The grammatical features seem to be pretty accurate:

- *y'all* as second person plural pronoun
- *Where is x at?* for *Where is x?*
- *You're done messed up* for *You have messed up*

His intonation also appears to be a quite accurate imitation. But what about how he pronounces the student's names?

- *Jacqueline* as [dʒeɪ'kwɔlɪn]
- *Blake* as [bə'lɑkeɪ]
- *Denise* as [di'naɪs]

These two seem too good to be true:

- *Aaron* as [eɪ'ʔeɪrɒn]
- *O'Shaughnessy [oʊʃeg'henesi]

Comment: The whole premise is that the substitute teacher is mispronouncing these names. I'm not sure I like the various subtexts in this sketch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentences accurately represent one form of African American Vernacular English. The names, however, do not represent how any black Americans that I have ever met would render those names. The pronunciation of those names in the sketch is a satire on how some black Americans choose deliberately unusual names. The implication is that the substitute teacher is accustomed to non-standard names and does not know how to parse common names.

The subject of naming choices among African Americans is a rich subject for comedians that has been mined numerous times.  It also holds interest for social scientists trying to understand those choices.  I have heard and read both in past, but I am having trouble putting my hands on such a source at this moment.